# CSS3 Animation buggy in Safari with after & before elements

Tags: css, animation, safari, webkit

i made a buffer animation of a 3d Cube. It works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but behaves wrongly in Safari. I dont know exactly what's causing the problem. I've been reading about some problems, where safari needs full percents to understand the animation, but I'm not using any, so that can't be the problem. But I guess it's probably something like that. Maybe someone has an idea. :)

Here's the Css, but I also made a pen in Codepen to view the animation (http://codepen.io/Vin-ni/pen/qOoJPQ)

```
.buffer {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:2;
  background:#f2f2f2;
  left:50%;
  top:50%;
  -webkit-transition: ease 0.5s;
          transition: ease 0.5s;
}
.buffer:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 50px;
  left:50px;
  background: #212121;
  -webkit-transform: skewY(45deg);
          transform: skewY(45deg); 
  margin-top:5px;
    -webkit-transition: ease 0.5s;
            transition: ease 0.5s;
}
.buffer:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 10px;
  top:50px;
  background: #969696;
  -webkit-transform: skewX(45deg);
          transform: skewX(45deg);
  margin-left:5px;
  -webkit-transition: ease 0.5s;
          transition: ease 0.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes buffer1 {
  from {margin-top: -25px;}
    to {margin-top: -35px;}
    from {margin-left: -25px;}
    to {margin-left: -35px;}
}

@keyframes buffer1 {
  from {margin-top: -25px;}
    to {margin-top: -35px;}
    from {margin-left: -25px;}
    to {margin-left: -35px;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes buffer2 {
    from {width: 10px;}
    to {width: 20px;}
    from {margin-top: 5px;}
    to {margin-top: 10px;}
}

@keyframes buffer2 {
    from {width: 10px;}
    to {width: 20px;}
    from {margin-top: 5px;}
    to {margin-top: 10px;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes buffer3 {
    from {height: 10px;}
    to {height: 20px;}
    from {margin-left: 5px;}
    to {margin-left: 10px;}
}
@keyframes buffer3 {
    from {height: 10px;}
    to {height: 20px;}
    from {margin-left: 5px;}
    to {margin-left: 10px;}
}

.buffer{
-webkit-animation: buffer1 0.5s  infinite alternate-reverse;
        animation: buffer1 0.5s  infinite alternate-reverse;

}
.buffer:after{
-webkit-animation: buffer2 0.5s infinite alternate-reverse ;
        animation: buffer2 0.5s infinite alternate-reverse ;

}
.buffer:before{
-webkit-animation: buffer3 0.5s infinite alternate-reverse;
        animation: buffer3 0.5s infinite alternate-reverse;

}
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. Safari has problems with redundant keyframes
my solution is

```
0%   {margin-top: -25px; margin-left: -25px;}
100% {margin-top: -35px; margin-left: -35px;}
```

or

```
from {margin-top: -25px; margin-left: -25px;}
to {margin-top: -35px; margin-left: -35px;}
```

instead of

```
from {margin-top: -25px;}
to {margin-top: -35px;}
from {margin-left: -25px;}
to {margin-left: -35px;}
```